# nginx - redirect only main domain to www, not subdomains

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https, subdomain

I'm new to Nginx and trying to figure out how to properly handle subdomains. What I want to achieve is that the main domain `example.com` is always redirected to `https://www.example.com`, but subdomains as `sub.example.com` should always be redirected to `https://sub.example.com`. In my current setup the first requirement is fulfilled, but `sub.example.com` always gets redirected to `https://www.sub.example.com`. What is the problem with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance, Fabian.

---

**My two server config files:**

*default*

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/on/my/server/to/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/on/my/server/to/privatekey.pem;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 default_server ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/on/my/server/to/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/on/my/server/to/privatekey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

*sub*

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/on/my/server/to/subcertificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/on/my/server/to/subprivatekey.pem;

    root /var/www/sub;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri = 404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm-web1.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current configuration also redirects `www.example.com` to `www.www.example.com`. Are you certain that the `sub` configuration file is being loaded? Try: `nginx -t` and `nginx -T`

Comment: Yes, the configuration files are loaded and strangely enough, it works now after I cleared the browser cache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this problem happens to anyone else: Try to clean your browser cache.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It is happening in every browser and even computer I use...